# Using JBoss Web SingleSignOn with JBoss Seam

Tags: jboss, seam, single-sign-on

Has anyone successfully used JBoss Web SingleSignOn with JBoss Seam, or know if it is possible? I have two web app:s that I would like to share the same login functionality, ie if you sign into one web app you do not need to sign in again when accessing the other web app.

Best regards

P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no official documentation on SSO.  This is partly due to the fact that the SSO integration didn't mature until Seam 2.x was established and there is little to no more development with Seam 2.x.  The push now is for Weld and Seam 3.  That doesn't meant there aren't solutions though that work well.  The Security and Seam developers are backing PicketLink as the SSO solution to use with Seam.

See the main PicketLink page for more information http://jboss.org/picketlink

And for Seam specific integration with PicketLink see:
How to add SAML and OpenID Authentication to your Seam Application -- http://community.jboss.org/docs/DOC-14752
External Authentication Example Using SSOCircle -- http://community.jboss.org/docs/DOC-14753
External Authentication Example Using OpenSSO -- http://community.jboss.org/docs/DOC-14763

Also there are examples in the community of Seam and SSO, for example: http://blogs.oracle.com/warren/entry/using_opensso_authentication_with_jboss

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge - a "master" Seam app users logged into (using SAML2) and sub features in "slave" web apps that I'd like to SSO users to.

I created a "CustomSingleSignOn" valve that enables SSO in this situation. Feel free to check it out:
https://github.com/jensaug/jbossweb-customsso

This valve can really be used for SSO-enabling any kind of custom sign in.

br,
Jens

Note:
I did this because I brutally failed to get SAML2 MetaData POST request to work with PicketLink in AS5. I guess there's a reason that the picketlink-quickstart "sales-metadata" was removed from the quicklink distro... And yes, compiling it from src (and the corresponding 2.1.7 picketlink version) didn't cut it.